# How can I declare an abstract generic class that inherits from another abstract class?

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance

I'm stumped on this one right now.

What I have: `public abstract class Class1<T> where T : SomeBaseClass, new()`

I want Class1 to inherit from:  `public abstract class Class2`.  How can I do this?  Can I do this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The inherited class comes before the [`where` clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384067.aspx).

```
public abstract class Class1<T> : Class2 where T : SomeBaseClass, new()
```

See also the MSDN page on [Generic Classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sz6zd40f.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

You just put the base class in before the template constraint.

```
public abstract class Class1<T> : Class2 where T : SomeBaseClass, new()
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put the inheritance clause before the generic type constraint.  It will be more readable, IMO, if the constraint is on a separate line.

```
public abstract class Class2
{
}

public abstract class Class1<T> : Class2
    where T : SomeBaseClass, new()
{
}
```